# Characteristic Function and Generalized Binomial Theorem

Tags: binomial-theorem, characteristic-functions

could you please help me on the following problem?

I have the characteristic functions  of two random variables $X$ and $Y$, denoted $\phi_X(u)$ and $\phi_Y(u)$, such that:
\begin{equation*}
  \phi_X(u) = \left(a + (1-a)\phi_Y(u) \right)^b
\end{equation*}
with $0<a<1$ and $b>0$.
I know the density of $Y$ and would like somehow to know the one of $X$.

If $1/2\le a<1$, I can write:
\begin{equation*}
  \phi_X(u) = a\left(1 + \frac{(1-a)}{a}\phi_Y(u) \right)^b
\end{equation*}
and I can apply the generalized binomial theorem because $\frac{(1-a)}{a}<1$ and $|\phi_Y(u)|<\le 1$.
Because I know the law of $Y$ I can get a sort of infinite mixture of densities that is fine for me.

However, I do not know how to proceed in case $0<a<1/2$.

Do you have some hints or ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance  for your help.

Comment: Characteristic functions are, in general, complex valued and there is a problem in defining $z^{b}$ for a complex number $z$. Are yo assuming that $\phi_Y$ is positive?

Comment: No I am not restricted to this assumption. I know for sure that both characteristic functions are well defined for $b>0$ and $0<a<1$. thanks

Comment: Why do you know that $\phi_Y$ is a characteristic function?  There are, for instance, very few characteristic functions $\phi_Z$ such that for each $b>0$, the function $\phi_Z^b$ is a characteristic function.  Your $a+(1-x)\phi_X$ must be one of them, if I understand your question right.

Comment: If for instance $Y$ is an exponential r.v. $\phi_X(u)$ is well defined. That’s actually where I started from.

Comment: Is $b$ an integer?

Comment: No it is a general positive number. For b integer I can use the standard binomial theorem and can get a simple result. Thanks